# How to find $x$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

How to find $x$? So I've founded an answer: $11$. I'm not sure too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is the last angle in the triangle ACE? You already know two, so you can find it.

The other angle at A can then be found since the two angles at A add up to 90°.

Now you know two angles in AEB, and you can find the remaining.

---

The general idea to solving these questions is that when you know two angles in a triangle, you can find the last, and when you know that two angles add up to 90° or 180°, you can find the other one.

Comment: I've tried but I couldn't do it.

Comment: @Hurry **Hint:** The angle $C\hat AE$ is $52$ because the angles in a triangle must add up to $180$. Can you continue now?

Comment: @Hurry be more specific, why couldn't you do it?